# Get list of users' profiles values with standard fields, like email

Tags: asp.net, profile

I have the ASP.NET application. I use authentication with user profiles. I use SQL Server as a data provider. What I want to do is to get fill the GridView control with all the users in the system with additional profile information.

For now I do like this:

```
UserAccounts.DataSource = Membership.GetAllUsers();
UserAccounts.DataBind();
```

With that I can make a list with fields: UserName and Email. But now I want to add First and LastName fields which I store as a Profile informations.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920533/how-to-get-list-of-user-profile-from-membership-provider) post and tried to do like this:

```
ProfileInfoCollection profiles = ProfileManager.GetAllProfiles(ProfileAuthenticationOption.All);
DateTime lastActivity = profiles["some_username"].Email;
```

but this gives me only standard user fields, like Email, LastActivityDate, etc. Later I've tried to call the function for ever row in GridView table.

```
public string GetProfileValue(string name, string UserName)
{
    ProfileBase pb = ProfileBase.Create(UserName, true);
    return pb.GetPropertyValue(name).ToString();
}
```

But I don't think it is efficient to query database for every field with profile information. I was thinking of joining `aspnet_Users` and `aspnet_Profile` tables, but the FirstName and LastName fields are stored like this:

```
UserId | PropertyNames                   | PropertyValuesString | ....
----------------------------------------------------------------------
someId | FirstName:S:0:6:LastName:S:6:5: | ThomasSmith          | ....
```

so that means that I have to parse the strings to get my values.

My questions are:

1. Is it a good policy to query the `aspnet_` tables directly using `SELECT`?
2. How to get the GridView which contain UserName, Email, LastActivityDate, FirstName, LastName (the standard and profile information together).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've found, the default ASP.NET profile provider stores all the profile information in a single, colon separated field for each user.

You'd be better off looking at the [SQL Table Profile Provider Sample](http://www.asp.net/downloads/sandbox/table-profile-provider-samples/) released by MS. This will enable you to create a nicely query-able table based profile, that you can then pass into your GridView.