# How can I display a collection in a GridView?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

i have multiple membership providers in my asp.net application.
i have access membership provider by using code:-

```
MembershipProvider mbr;
mbr = Membership.Providers["CustomMembershipProvider"];
```

I want to fetch all users and display in grid view. How i can i do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Get List of User/Profile from Membership Provider?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920533/how-to-get-list-of-user-profile-from-membership-provider)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [MembershipProvider.GetAllUsers Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.getallusers.aspx):

```
int total;
var users = mbr.GetAllUsers(0, int.MaxValue, out total);
```

or pass an index and page size if you have a paging grid.

And here an ASPX fragment defining the gridview:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GV"></asp:GridView>
```

And the corresponding code-behind C# class:

```
public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // create membership instance...
        int total;
        GV.DataSource = mbr.GetAllUsers(0, int.MaxValue, out total);
        GV.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @Simon i have already try :-var users = mbr.GetAllUsers(0, int.MaxValue, out total); it returns total=9.but not displaying in gridview.

Comment: @MohitArora: Then your question is all wrong. You don't need help with getting a list of users from a MembershipProvider. What you REALLY want help with is "How to display a collection in a grid". Please delete the question and google for the answer.

Comment: If you cannot find anything relevant then search SO for the answer. If you still can't find any relevant information, write a new question specifying what you REALLY want help with.

Comment: hi @SimonMourier thanks its working. i know how to bind grid view but user list count was 0 in membershipuserproviders but when i move the cursor on total by using breakpoint its showing 0 i.e out total=9;